# Strange Google Play Optimization Tip

Tags: android, console, google-play

After publishing my app, I got this confusing Optimization tip:

```
You translated the APK into French but not the store listing.
```

My APK is still in English (default) and German.
I've set up the /values/string.xml (en) and the /values/strings.xml (de).

So, does anyone know why i'm getting this message?

Comment: check carefully for any french resources in your source code. Any string value or folder for `fr`.

Comment: Thank you Rahul, i don't have any french resources. Maybe it is, because i use In-APP-Products?!

Comment: what could be relation between n-APP-Products and french?